# How to deploy a pytorch model?

Tags: deployment, deep-learning, pytorch, style-transfer

I trained a model for Style Transfer and trained it on 1000's of images. I saved the Model for every 1000 of images and also saved the Transform Network final weights. Now I want it to be saved as a model so that I can use it in an app but none of the search are giving me a clear answer how to do that.

```
VG1 = vgg.VGG16("/kaggle/working/transformer_weight.pth")
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 800, 800)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.script(VG1, example)
traced_script_module.save('kaggle/working')
```

but it gives

```
RuntimeError: 
Module 'Sequential' has no attribute '_modules' :
  File "/kaggle/working/vgg.py", line 43
        layers = {'3': 'relu1_2', '8': 'relu2_2', '15': 'relu3_3', '22': 'relu4_3'}
        features = {}
        for name, layer in self.features._modules.items():
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- HERE
            x = layer(x)
            if name in layers:
```

I am beginner and I have been trying for days. Pls tell if you want more information.
I want to save the model so that I can use it to an android studio to make app.

The notebook is in 'https://www.kaggle.com/starktony45/fast-neural-style'

Comment: How do you want to serve the model? What platform are you targeting? The question needs more details.

Comment: Ok thanks. i will add that